# Ubuntu 17.10 NVIDIA GeForce 7025 Legacy Drivers problem 304.137

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 17.10

I was using Ubuntu 16.10 with NVIDIA Proprietary drivers, I was asked to update to 17.10, so I did, installed everything, purged unnecessary programs and files and restarted, now Ubuntu boots to a black screen with just the mouse.

Things I tried:

- updating the linux headers and reinstalling the driver,
- disabling wayland in conf file,
- using `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` in grub, booting in `nomodeset` in grub,
- `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`,
- installing the driver from the .run file downloaded from nvidia site.

The only solution for me so far was `sudo apt purge nvidia-*` and use Nouveau driver which hangs and froze my system if I try to open things fast and is slow to render animations like open "Show Aplications". I was reading about some fight between nvidia and some open source programs to use a standard in the codes and that is causing the drivers issues and nvidia don't like Wayland.

I am very new to Linux and stuff and it's getting hard to like the system with all the bugs that you hope are gone with an update.

Comment: Which versions of the NVIDIA driver did you try? Which kernel is installed currently (`uname -a`)?

Comment: nVidia proprietary  drivers do not work with Wayland. try an Xorg session

Comment: I was trying nvidia 304.137 driver with 4.13.0-17-generic kernel.

Comment: @ravery can you help me with this situation? In the settings its saying that I'm using NV4C graphics, I purged all nvidia drivers and files and did `sudo apt autoremove`, if I use a Xorg session can I use nvidia proprietary drivers or am I currently using a Xorg session? I'm very new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, trying to get Nvidia Optimus to work after upgrading to 17.10. I tried a lot of what you did before switching from low latency to generic headers, which completely bricked my system.

The only way I got it working was reformatting the hard drive and doing a clean install of 17.10. For whatever reason upgrading from an earlier version seems to cause problems.

Obviously you'll want to save your data first if you go that route.

Comment: I did not tried to do a clean install of Ubuntu yet, what is your card and witch  driver are you using?

Comment: The Nvidia Quadro M1000 and driver 384.

Answer (score 0):

My situation is absolutely the same.

```
uname -a
```

Linux thiago-desktop 4.13.0-17-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 6 10:04:08 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000003D6sv00001849sd000003D6bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : C61 [GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a]
driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

After the black screen showing only the mouse I've finally open the terminal and entered `sudo apt-get purge '^nvidia'`.